# How to compute the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure for given intervals

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let u be a Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure on the Borel σ-algebra. Let Fu be the associated function such that u([a,b)) = Fu(b)−Fu(a).

Calculate

a) u([a,b]); in terms of the function Fu.
b) u((a,b)); in terms of the function Fu.
c) u((a,b]); in terms of the function Fu.

My solution

for part a) u([a,b]) = $u(\bigcap_n^\infty [a,b-\frac{1}{n}) = lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} u[a,b-\frac{1}{n}) = lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}  (Fu(b-\frac{1}{n}) - Fu(a) = Fu(b^-)-Fu(a)$

for part b) u((a,b)) = $u(\bigcap_n^\infty [a-\frac{1}{n},b) = lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} u[a-\frac{1}{n},b) = lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}  (Fu(b) - Fu(a-\frac{1}{n}) = Fu(b)-Fu(a^-)$

for part c) u((a,b]) = $u(\bigcap_n^\infty [a-\frac{1}{n},b+\frac{1}{n}) = lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} u[a-\frac{1}{n},b+\frac{1}{n}) = lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}  (Fu(b+\frac{1}{n}) - Fu(a-\frac{1}{n}) = Fu(b^+)-Fu(a^-)$

Comment: I think your intersections should be unions here....

Comment: Why unions instead of intersections?

Comment: The intersection $\bigcap_{n}^{\infty}[a,b-\frac{1}{n})$, for example, is not equal to $[a,b]$.  Since $\frac{1}{n}$ is maximized when $n=1$, the intersection is equal to $[a,b-1)\subset [a,b]$.